# Create a plane that trims cube Pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet, clipping, opengl-compat

I have a moving, zooming, rotating cube, I need to create a plane that will trim the cube like that[image]

Here is the code of drawing

```
pgl.glLoadIdentity()
pgl.glViewport(650, 500, 650, 500)
pgl.glMatrixMode(ogl.GL_PROJECTION)
pgl.glLoadIdentity()

pgl.gluPerspective(self.dist, 1.3, 1, 1000)

pgl.glMatrixMode(ogl.GL_MODELVIEW)

pgl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -400)

pgl.glPushMatrix()
pgl.glTranslatef(self.x, self.y, self.z)
pgl.glRotatef(self.xRotation, 1, 0, 0)
pgl.glRotatef(self.yRotation, 0, 1, 0)
pgl.glRotatef(self.zRotation, 0, 0, 1)
pgl.glScalef(self.zoom, self.zoom, self.zoom)


if not transparant:
    pgl.glPolygonMode(pgl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, pgl.GL_FILL)
else:
    pgl.glPolygonMode(pgl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, pgl.GL_LINE)

draw_big()

pgl.glPopMatrix()
```

Comment: Do you want to clip the cube, so that you can see inside the cube or do you want to put a triangle on the edge which closes the mesh?

Comment: i want to see inside, i tryed to use glOrtho, but i don't know how to put it not in front of screen, but on the left side for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) fixed function pipeline you can set a clipping plane.

There can be more than 1 clip plane and the planes have to be enabled by [`glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANEi)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml).

The plane is set by [`glClipPlane`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClipPlane.xml). The parameters to the clipping plane are interpreted as a [Plane Equation](http://www.songho.ca/math/plane/plane.html).
The first 3 components of the plane equation are the normal vector to the clipping plane. The 4th component is the distance to the origin:

```py
plane = plane = [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -280]
ogl.glClipPlane(pgl.GL_CLIP_PLANE0, plane)
```

For a detailed specification see [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification - 13.7. PRIMITIVE CLIPPING](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf); page 537.
Note, that the inverse of the current model-view matrix is applied to the clipping plane coefficients at the time when it is specified.

See the example, which is based on the code of the question:

```py
def on_draw(self) :

    self.clear()
    pgl.glClear(pgl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | pgl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    pgl.glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500)

    pgl.glMatrixMode(ogl.GL_PROJECTION)
    pgl.glLoadIdentity()
    pgl.gluPerspective(45, 1, 1, 1000)

    pgl.glMatrixMode(ogl.GL_MODELVIEW)
    pgl.glLoadIdentity()
    pgl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -400)

    pgl.glPushMatrix()
    pgl.glTranslatef(self.x, self.y, self.z)
    pgl.glRotatef(self.xRotation, 1, 0, 0)
    pgl.glRotatef(self.yRotation, 0, 1, 0)
    pgl.glRotatef(self.zRotation, 0, 0, 1)
    pgl.glScalef(self.zoom, self.zoom, self.zoom)

    if not transparant:
        pgl.glPolygonMode(pgl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, pgl.GL_FILL)
    else:
        pgl.glPolygonMode(pgl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, pgl.GL_LINE)

    # set and enable clip plane
    plane = plane = [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -280]
    ogl.glEnable(pgl.GL_CLIP_PLANE0)
    ogl.glClipPlane(pgl.GL_CLIP_PLANE0, plane)

    draw_big()
    ogl.glDisable(pgl.GL_CLIP_PLANE0)

    pgl.glPopMatrix()
```

[image]